# ¿Por qué "estirar la pata" es "morir"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones

El Diccionario de la Lengua recoge la expresión [**estirar la pata**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S71hGRM) como

> 1. loc. verb. coloq. **morir** (‖ llegar al término de la vida).

¿Por qué ese significado de "estirar la pata"?

Comment: Sin conocimiento de causa(por eso no lo pongo como respuesta), yo diría que es una clara alusión al rigor mortis. Sinceramente, lo he visto tan claro siempre que nunca me molesté en buscarlo, aunque podría tener otro origen perfectamente.

Comment: Igual que Nox, yo lanzo solo una hipótesis. Quizá esté relacionada con *kick the bucket*, que sí sé que hace alusión a dar la patada al cubo al que te subes antes de ahorcarte.

Aunque también se me viene a la cabeza la típica imagen del animal muerto con una pata estirada.

Comment: Wikipedia https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disfemismo indica que es un  disfemismo, pero sin explicaciones adicionales: "Un disfemismo es una palabra o expresión deliberadamente despectiva o insultante que se emplea en lugar de otra más neutral.... El disfemismo es lo contrario del eufemismo. Este fenómeno lingüístico ... recoge palabras o expresiones de carácter despectivo que denotan una realidad mucho más dura y desagradable que ya por sí manifiesta el tabú lingüístico. **Un ejemplo de disfemismo es "espicharla" o "estirar la pata" por morir.**"

Comment: Siempre supuse que era porque a los muertos se los hace yacer con las piernas extendidas, pero nunca me preocupé por confirmarlo y, hasta ahora, no encontré fuentes confiables que lo confirmen.

Comment: La primera aparición de la expresión es en el diccionario de la RAE, edición de 1791, en la que "estirar la pierna" equivalía a "morirse". Se ve que luego cambiamos "pierna" por "pata". Curioso que si lo pones en plural: "estirar las piernas", ya en 1737 se decía que equivalía a "pasearse".

Comment: @JMVanPelt curiously the English equivalent is turn up ones toes. Usual used as a comic phrase by the way.

Answer (score 7):

Según se comenta en [Definiciencia Popular - estirar la pata](http://definicienciapopular.blogspot.com.es/2008/11/estirar-la-pata.html), el origen de *estirar la pata* radica en la forma en que mueren los pajaritos:

> El origen de estirar la pata, según la fidedignísima aseveración de nuestro gran amigo, el frondosamente experimentado y nunca bien ponderado José “El Antiguo”, radica en la forma en que mueren los pajaritos. (...) los canarios y otros tipos de aves de diminuto porte, domésticas o silvestres (las cuales en mi país llamamos, con inspirada originalidad, pajaritos), al morir adoptan una rigidez característica: con las patas estiradas hacia delante, las cuales, al yacer sobre el dorso los cuerpos a los que aun pertenecen, quedan apuntando hacia el cenit en lugar de apuntar hacia abajo, como cuando se hallan parados.

Answer (score 0):

Estirar la pata, es un acto reflejo involuntario. Todos estiramos la pata al morir. Es más, a veces por error lo hacemos cuando entramos en sueño. Todos hemos experimentado ese despertar súbito dando una patada. Es un intento desesperado de tu cerebro por hacerte reaccionar ante la muerte inminente. Si realmente mueres, pues es lo último que haces: estirar la pata.